# @media {width:568px} not working in chrome instead it is taking style of @media {max-width:599px} and {min-width:599}

Tags: css, google-chrome

```
@media(width: 568px)
{
//style//
}


@media (max-width: 599px) and (min-width: 480px) 
{
//style//
}
```

Media query for width 568px is not working in chrome but it is taking style of media max-width: 599px and min-width: 480px. In fire-fox it is working correctly. As I have read related problems with mine I tried and check my brackets and other stuff. I am new to media queries so want to know about mainly used break points and about my chrome issue.

Answer (score 5):

include this in `<head></head>`

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> <-- user-scalable=yes if you want user to allow zoom -->
```

change you @media style as this

```
@media only screen (max-width: 568px) {
 // or as per your needs, as I try to explain below
}
```

Now I try to explain maybe..:)

```
@media (max-width:568px)
```

for a window with a `max-width` of `568px` that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:568px)
```

for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of `568px` apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:568px)
```

Here is a [quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘`only`’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "`only`", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

I try to put some more information here, gathered from web.

```
@media all and (min-width: 600px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) and (min-width: 300px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 299px) {
}
```

**If**

That's what media queries are: logical if statements. "If" these things are true about the browser, use the CSS inside.

**And**

The keyword and.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

**Or**

Comma separate.

```
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Technically these are treated like to separate media queries, but that is effectively and or.

**Not**

Reverse the logic with the keyword not.

```
@media not all and (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Just doing not (max-width: 600px) doesn't seem to work for me, hence the slightly funky syntax above. Perhaps someone can explain that to me. Note that not only works for the current media query, so if you comma separate, it only affects the media query it is within. Also note that not reverses the logic for the entire media query as a whole, not individual parts of it. not x and y = not (x and y) ≠ (not x) and y

**Exclusive**

To ensure that only one media query is in effect at time, make the numbers (or whatever) such that that is possible. It may be easier to mentally manage them this way.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Logically this is a bit like a switch statement, only without a simple way to do "if none of these match do this" like default.

**Overriding**

There is nothing preventing more than one media query from being true at the same time. It may be more efficient to use this in some cases rather than making them all exclusive.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Media queries add no specificity to the selectors they contain, but source order still matters. The above will work because they are ordered correctly. Swap that order and at browser window widths above 800px the background would be red, perhaps unintuitively.

**Mobile First**

Your small screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets larger you override what you need to. So, min-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

**Desktop First**

Your large screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets smaller you override what you need to. So, max-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

You can be as complex as you want with this.

```
@media 
  only screen and (min-width: 100px),
  not all and (min-width: 100px),
  not print and (min-height: 100px),
  (color),
  (min-height: 100px) and (max-height: 1000px),
  handheld and (orientation: landscape)
{
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Note the only keyword was intended to prevent non-media-query supporting browsers to not load the stylesheet or use the styles. Not sure how useful that ever was / still is.

[And for media queries priorites](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/media_queries_priority.htm)

sources : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored-or-overridden/10816111#10816111) [two](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) [three](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) [four](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) [five](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: thanks Gaurav for your reply, I wanna ask if class's and Id's are same in "@media (max-width: 568px)" and in "@media (max-width: 599px) and @media (min-width: 499px)", then??. And i want media query for iPhone5 lanscape view can you tell me the specific one media query for. I tried your syntax still the issue is same

Comment: max-width: 568px will apply til browser width reaches max width of 568px, i.e all sizes less than 568px, while same applies for 599px, so if you use both 568px and 599px , then 599px will only apply between 568px and 598px, below 568px your styles in 568px will apply, and if you use all the 3 above then priorities will take effect as there will be clash between them read https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/media_queries_priority.htm Also I am making an edit to make you clear about media queries.

Answer (score 2):

@media **width** is not possible, it's either min-width or max-width, or both.

Comment: i have tried that also but still it not working. and this is my second site which i making responsive i use same media queries in first one also and it is working correctly. Suggest me if  you have alternative for iPhone 5 landscape view.

Comment: @Rahul checkout this site - http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ - all media queries are listed for each device.

Comment: hiii,,,i want to ask one more thing does old iPhone version support scrolling,becuase on old version iphone i am having problem that where scroll is needed like in table or in pop-up structures i am using overflow-x:scroll property..but in older device it is not working.And in in new version scroll is working but not visible same thin in android devices...please let me no if any solution is available.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem in Chrome while developing a grid system. I was watching the values in the element inspector trigger for all but one media query at 599px. Everything in the CSS was written correctly.

What worked for me, was adding the meta tag for viewport scaling in my HTML markup as such:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Scaling the window via the element inspector without it never triggered the query, but manually sizing the browser window sometimes did.