# How to do mobile devices-friendly CSS for both desktop and mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries, desktop

It may be my ignorance, but I think any newbie question is welcome where there's an opportunity to distinguish between right and wrong.

For responsive and mobile-friendly design, I'm using

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){}
```

from the very beginning with success. However when I uploaded the site to the server and browsed the site from mobile devices, it's not working. Then I learned to use

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width: 800px){}
```

Now it's working fine (Note: the `-device` in the middle).

But with `-device` in place I can't see the preview when developing the site in my desktop PC. So when I'm developing, I'm using without `-device`, and after upload I'm using the `-device` in the middle. It's a bit odd to me.

Recently I faced an interview board, where I submitted one of my mobile-devices friendly site for review, but when they resized the browser, it's not working because on the live site I used `-device` in the media query. So, it's a bit odd for me.

Is there a way I can code so that the code both works in Desktop with its media queries and also in mobile devices. I tried

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) and (max-device-width: 800px) {}
```

But FAILED in my Desktop. :(

Is there a way?

#### EDIT

To acknowledge that, I'm in the right way, I'm using

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

in my `<head></head>` tag. And using [Respond.min.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) also.

Comment: Try refering this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995

Comment: you got the idea or still need some help, I will try to post that answer  here with added information.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gaurav. Your answer is much informative for me to get into this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @media  screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:960px){
    xxxx

}
@media screen and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width:1024px){
       xxxxx
}
```

[`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/n8fkU/)

Comment: What's the difference? Is it working on mobile devices?

Comment: yes my frinds you veiew example website you look. all browser support https://wrapbootstrap.com/

Comment: Hope with your support and direction, I'm now walking on the track I think. Thank you very much. Will let you know the final product with your guidance inshALLAH. :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

max-device-width is the width of the rendering area of the device,

max-width is the width of the target display area

max-width is the proper way to go with. Did you place de viewport meta tag in your HTML page?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1>
```