# Media Queries are not following corresponding to correct stylesheet

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have created a website to test out media queries and have the following in my stylesheet:

```
@media(max-width:4096px){...}
@media(max-width:1920px){...}    
@media(max-width:1440px){...}
@media(max-width:1366px){...}
@media(max-width:1136px){...}
@media(max-width:1080px){...}
@media(max-width:1024px){...}
@media(max-width:980px){...}
@media(max-width:960px){...}
@media(max-width:768px){...}
@media(max-width:720px){...}
@media(max-width:640px){...}
@media(max-width:320px){...}
```

The problem is that whenever I am on Firefox Responsive Design tool and I scale to different resolutions (say 1366px for example). Instead of loading the `1366px` styles it will load the styles from `1440px`.

This happens for all the queries not just `1366px`. However when I try this on Chrome I do not get that issue. I use Chrome 36 and Firefox 30, so I don't think there is a problem with the version.

Is there anyway to make my website re-size without this issue, and why is this issue occurring? 
Thanks.

Comment: Do you modify different properties in the queries or is it the same one in each?

Comment: You can refer this for details in media query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to include min-width example;

```
@media(max-width:1440px) AND (min-width:1367px){...}
@media(max-width:1366px) AND (min-width:1137px){...}
```

This will help eliminate conflicts.

Comment: I thought this at first, but CSS cascades, and the order is correct

Comment: Roderick, it might still conflict even though it does cascade. - I always use max width and min width to be more specific, and reduce possible collisions hehe. 

It might not be it, but at least he'll be sure

Comment: Yeah, setting both upper and lower limits actually *blocks* cascading, which can be useful in certain situations. However this may not be 100% reliable, not sure with pixels but it is definitely a problem when you use relative units such as ems.

Comment: It all comes down to wether its the exact same properties being modified or not. If its the same, rely on the cascade. If they are different set upper/lower bounds.

Comment: Its not reliable to use with EMS BoltClock, but I did use upper and lower bounds for a few websites using pixels, and it works fine. Than it depends if the person has a problem and is forced to use upper and lower bounds or use the normal cascading built-in.

Comment: And I also believe that the problem comes from the browsers mostly, not from our side.