# How to fit the screen in every different resolution in php?

Tags: android, css

I am developing an android application that using webview to display the content for certain website. Unfortunately, it doesn't fit in every gadget. In Android TV the content looks bigger, but in mobile it fits. Where should I take care of it? in CSS or Android Java? Any solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Determine the resolution. For example, if your screen resolution is 1000x800px. Use this in CSS :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
#yourelement
{
....
}

}
```