# Change CSS according to screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working a mobile application using angularjs and ionic framework.My application is for both Tab and Mobile versions. I cant use the same CSS for Tab and Mobile, so is there a way to detect the screen size and change the CSS accordingly?

I found a jquery code that does this but i'm not sure if i can use this in angularjs.If i can how?

http://www.master-script.com/detect-screen-size-with-jquery-and-apply-a-css-style.html

Can i have a step by step instructions on how to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Hope this helps , can also use bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look into Media Queries. You can have sets for width or height ranges. Max width and min width. Viewports for specific devices.