# Why does this media-selector get active on a wider page?

Tags: css

I use the following media-selector:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 651px)
```

for some reason, the following css-snippet from inside that media selector get's triggered on a page that is 810 pixels wide.

```
.bar .link{
    width: 92%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

None of the other css from the media-selector get's triggered. Why? Below is the full Css.

```
/* ==========================================================================
   HTML5 Boilerplate styles - h5bp.com (generated via initializr.com)
   ========================================================================== */

html,
button,
input,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    color: #222;
}

body {
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

::selection {
    background: #b3d4fc;
    text-shadow: none;
}

hr {
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

fieldset {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}

.chromeframe {
    margin: 0.2em 0;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 0.2em 0;
}

input:invalid, textarea:invalid {
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
/* ==========================================================================
   Author's custom styles
   ========================================================================== */
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}


body{
    max-width: 810px;
    background: #e9e2d9;
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: center;
}
h1,h2{
    color: #002244;
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 36px;
    padding: 32px 0 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.apply h2,.pitch h2{
    padding-top: 50px;
}
h3{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #002244;
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-top: 0;
    line-height: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

p, a{
    color: #002244;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
a{
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

span{
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
label span{
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
button[disabled], html input[disabled] {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
.section.pitch{
    background: #e9e2d9;
    padding-top: 25px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}
.section.details h3{
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 170px;
    top: 72px;
}

p.details{
    margin-bottom: -12px;
}
p.important{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -6px;
}
p.minor{
    text-align: justify;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.vote{
    margin: 0 70px 63px 70px;
    max-width: 670px;
}
.vote .byline{
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: 3px auto 0;
}
.special{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #e9e2d9;
    background-color: #002244;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 12px 0 6px 0;
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    margin: 35px 0 0 0;
    height: 30px;
}

.special p{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #e9e2d9;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    display: inline;
}

.bar{
    width: 33%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0 32px 0;
}
.bar:hover {
    background: white;
}
.bar .link{
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
.bar:hover .link{
    background: white;
}
.bar .link p{
    padding: 0 0 7px 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.bar .link a{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.bar .link img{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 206px;;
}
.bar .link .after{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 206px;
    background-color: #002244;
    text-align: right;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0;
}
.bar .link .after a{
    color: #e9e2d9;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 4px 6px 4px 0
}
.bar .like{
    width: 93%;
    background-color: #002244;
    margin: 0 auto 8px auto;
    height: 75px;
}
.bar .like p{
    color: #e9e2d9;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 9px;
    padding: 6px 0 18px 0;
    margin: 0 30px;
    line-height: 1.2em;
}
.bar .like .fb_iframe_widget{
    padding: 8px 0 13px 0;
}
.bar .like p.percentage{
    padding: 13px 0 0 0;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.compact{
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}
.compact a{
    line-height: 1em;
}
.small{
    font-size: 9px;
    clear: both;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: justify;
}
.instruction .count{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0!important;
    margin-left: -26px;
    left: 50%;
}
.count{
    color: transparent;
    margin: 11px auto 5px auto;
    height: 50px;
    width: 52px;
}
.count1{
    background: url("../img/1.png") no-repeat center;
}
.count2{
    background: url("../img/2.png") no-repeat center;
}
.count3{
    background: url("../img/3.png") no-repeat center;
}
.count4{
    background: url("../img/4.png") no-repeat center;
}
.disclaimer{
    padding-bottom: 32px;
    border-top: 1px solid #002244;
}
.disclaimer h2{
    padding: 40px 0 16px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.disclaimer p{
    font-size: 10px;
}
a.label{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 8px 12px 7px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #002244;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/*justify last line hack*/
p.details:after
{content: "";
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;}

.fieldset{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    opacity: 0.3;
    margin-top: 24px;
}


.fieldset:first-child{
    opacity: 1;
}
.video-container{
    height: 0;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
}

.video-container .videopreview{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    background: url("../img/movieposter.png") no-repeat center #002244;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-size: contain;;
}
.video-container iframe{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.section{
    padding: 0 46px 32px;
    opacity: 0;
    float: left;
}
.section.blue{
    background-image: url('../img/whitearrow.png'), url('../img/bluearrow.png');
    background-position:  top center, bottom center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-color: #002244;
    color: #e9e2d9;
    padding: 22px 45px 52px;
}
.section.blue h2,.section.blue h3, .section.blue p{
    color: #e9e2d9;
}
.jury {
    padding: 24px 0 15px;
}
.jury div{
    width: 24%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0;
}
.jury div a{
    color: white;
    background-color: #e9e2d9;
    width: 120px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1em;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.jury div a span{
    color: #002244;
}
.jury div a span span{
    text-decoration: underline;
}


.show{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.showmany>*{
    opacity: 1 !important;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.showmany>.n2{
    transition-delay: .2s;
}
.showmany>.n3{
    transition-delay: .4s;
}
.showmany>.n4{
    transition-delay: .6s;
}
.mathieu .mathieu,.mathieu .mathieu:hover{
    background-image: url('../img/mathieu.jpg');
    top: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}
.mathieu .mathieu span{
    display: none;
}
.hirmane .hirmane, .hirmane .hirmane:hover {
    background-image: url('../img/hirmane.jpg');
    top: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}

.hirmane .hirmane span{
    display: none;
}
.daniel .daniel,.daniel .daniel:hover{
    background-image: url('../img/daniel.jpg');
    top: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}
.daniel .daniel span{
    display: none;
}
.laura .laura,.laura .laura:hover{
    background-image: url('../img/laura.jpg');
    top: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 0;
}
.laura .laura span{
    display: none;
}

.jury div a span span{
    display: block;
    font-size: 8px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding-top: 8px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.jury div p{
   min-height: 2em;
   letter-spacing: 0;
   margin: 1em auto;
}
.memeberdetailswrapper{
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all .5s;
}
.memeberdetailswrapper.expanded{
    height: 115px;
    transition: all .5s;
}

.memberdetails{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s;
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -100px;
}

.memberdetails.visible{
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all .3s;
    transition-delay: .3s;
}

.instruction {
    width: 170px;
    height: 210px;
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 9px 27px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.instruction p{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.documentholder{
    color: white;
    margin: 20px 30px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.documentholder div{
    background-size: 41px 51px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.documentholder .document{
    background: url('../img/document.png') center no-repeat #002244;
    background-size: 41px 51px;
}
.documentholder .photo{
    background: url('../img/photo.png') center no-repeat #002244;
    background-size: 60px auto;
}
.documentholder .video{
    background: url('../img/video.png') center no-repeat #002244;
    background-size: 60px auto;
}
.documentholder p {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.documentholder p.opt {
    font-size: 9px;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.fieldset.mybutton{
    opacity: 1;
}

.mybutton{
    clear: both;
}
/* General button style (reset) */
input.mybtn, a.mybtn {
    max-width: 100%;
    white-space: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 10px auto 27px auto;
    width: auto;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 16px 27px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    color: #002244;
    line-height: 1em;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.documentholder div,.back,.jury div a,.label,input.mybtn, a.mybtn {
    box-shadow: 0 6px;
    position: relative;
}

.documentholder div:after,.back:after,.jury div a:after,.label:after,.mybtn:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
.documentholder div:hover,.back:hover,.jury div a:hover,.label:hover,.mybtn:hover{
    box-shadow: 0 4px;
    top: 2px;
}
.documentholder div:active,.back:active,.jury div a:active,.label:active,.mybtn:active {
    box-shadow: 0 0;
    top: 6px;
}
.instructions h2{
    padding: 19px 0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.footer{
    background: url('../img/footerlogo.png') top center no-repeat #002244;
    height: 220px;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
.footer p{
    color: #e9e2d9;;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 18px;
    right: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#legal{
    position: fixed;
    width: 810px;
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    z-index: 5;
}
#legal p{
    padding: 6px 0 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.mybtn.computerbtn{
    display: none;
}
.backwrapper{
    position: absolute;
    left: 17px;
}
.backwrapperlast{
    position: absolute;
    left: 17px;
    top: 43px;
}


.back{
    height: 48px;
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    color: #002244;
    background: url('../img/back.png') 8px 12px no-repeat white;
    border-radius: 24px;
}
.fbshare{
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.share{
    display: block;
}
.jury div.memeberdetailmobile{
    display: none
}
.clockwrapper p.clock {
    font-size: 90px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 86px;
    margin: 20px 0 0px;
    line-height: 90px;
}
.clockwrapper p.clock span {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}
.clockwrapper p{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 138px;
    margin: 0 0 40px;
    font-size: 10px;
}
.knowmore{
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
.countdown .byline {
    padding-top: 4px;
    line-height: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.submission{
    padding: 38px 77px;
}
.submission.likething{
    padding: 1px;
}
.likething .fb_iframe_widget{
    position: relative;
    top: -7px;
    display: inline!important;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 0;
}

.submission .special p{
    line-height: 0px;
    display: inline;
    font-size: 21px;
}
.submission .special p.likedetails{
    position: relative;
    top: -11px;
    line-height: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.submission img{
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.submission .content{
    text-align: left;
}
.submission .content .left{
    float: left;
    max-width: 381px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
.submission .content .entrepreneur .special{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.submission .content .entrepreneur p{
    font-size: 11px;
    text-transform: none;
}
.submission .content .entrepreneur p.name{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 10px;
    line-height: 0px;
}
.submission .content .entrepreneur{
    padding: 6px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 206px;
    background: white;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.submission .special{
    margin: 0 0 6px 0;
}
.submission .content .entrepreneur img{
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.submission .project h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
} 
.submission .project p{
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-top: 4px;
}
.content .quote {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
.content .quote p {
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 1em;
    text-transform: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.content .quote p.mentor {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: GillSansMTStd-Medium;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-top: 13px;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
.submission .social{
    clear: both;
    height: 82px;
}
.submission .social .socialheader{
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 20px 0 1px;
}
.submission .social p{
    color: #e9e2d8;
    margin: 0 60px;
}
.submission .social>div{
    max-width: 315px;
    background-color: #002244;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 82px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.submission .social .sharebox{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 0
}
.submission .social>.sharebox.wider {
    width: 100%;
}
.submission .social img{
    width: auto;
}
p.likedetails, span.likedetails{
    font-size: 11px !important;
    display: block !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
.social p.likedetails, .social span.likedetails{
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 10px!important;
}
.submission .social .sharebox .socialheader {
    margin: 27px 0 1px 0;
}
.social .fb_iframe_widget{
    padding-top: 0;
}
.faded{
    opacity: .6;
}
/* ==========================================================================
   Media Queries
   ========================================================================== */

@media only screen and (max-width: 651px) {
    .jury div.memeberdetailmobile{
        display: block;
        max-height: 0;
        transition: all .5s;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .jury div.memeberdetailmobile.visible{
        max-height: 300px
    }
    .section{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .jury div{
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .memeberdetailswrapper{
        display: none;
    }
    .instruction{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    .mybtn.computerbtn{
        /*display: inline-block;*/
    }
    .mybtn.applybtn{
        /*display: none;*/
    }
    .jury div a{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .jury div p{
        margin: 1em auto 2em auto;
    }
    .documentholder{
        padding: 20px 0;
        width: 33%;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .documentholder div{
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
    }
    .documentholder .video {
        background-size: 43px auto;
    }
    .documentholder .photo {
        background-size: 37px auto;
    }
    .documentholder .document {
        background-size: 27px auto;
    }
    .qq-upload-list{
        width: 75%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .qq-upload-file{
        font-size: 10px;
    }
    #legal{
        bottom: -104px;
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
    #legal p{
        letter-spacing: 0;
    }
    .apply input, .apply textarea{
        font-size: 11px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .apply input[type="submit"]{
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .footer{
        background-size: contain;
        position: relative;
        bottom: 6px;
    }
    .backwrapper, .backwrapperlast{
        top: 17px;
    }
    .pitch h2{
        padding-top: 24px;
    }
    h2{
        font-size: 23px;

    }
    .thankswrapper h2{
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    .thankswrapper .share {
       margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .mobilehide{
        display: none;
    }
    p.offset{
        margin-top: 2em;
    }
    .instruction{
        height: auto;
    }
    .instruction h3{
        margin-top: 1em;
    }
    .instruction,.instruction p,.section.details h3, .instruction .count{
        position: static;
    }
    .instruction .count{
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .memberdetails {
        height: auto;
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
    .fieldset{
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .footer p{
        font-size: 9px;
    }
    .clockwrapper p.clock {
        font-size: 39px;
        letter-spacing: 4px;
        margin: 0px 0 0px;
        height: 33px;
        line-height: 1em;    
    }
    .clockwrapper p {
        width: 55px;
        margin: -5px 0 24px;
        font-size: 9px;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 5px;
        position: relative;
    }
    .days{
        left: -10px;
    }
    .hours{
        left: -5px;
    }
    .min{
        right: -2px;
    }
    .sec{
        right: -6px;
    }
    .clockwrapper p.clock span {
       top: -4px;
    }
    .vote{
        margin: 0 4% 63px 4%;
    }
    .bar{
        width: 100%;
    }
    }
    .bar:hover, .link .bar:hover {
        background: transparent;
    }
    .bar .link{
        width: 92%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .bar .like{
        width: 206px;
    }
    .vote .special{
        font-size: 11px;
    }
    .submission {
        padding: 57px 17px;
    }
    .submission h1{
        font-size: 26px;
    }
    .submission .special{
        height: auto;
        padding: 12px 9px 0 9px;
    }
    .submission .special p.likedetails{
        line-height: 1em;
        font-size: 10px !important;
    }
    .submission .content .left{
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: justify;
    }
    .submission .social>div{
        height: auto;
        margin-top: 20px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        max-width: 100%;

    }
    .submission .social .sharebox{
        display: none;
    }
    .submission .content .entrepreneur{
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .submission .content .entrepreneur img{
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media print,
       (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 5/4),
       (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25),
       (min-resolution: 120dpi) {

}

/* ==========================================================================
   Helper classes
   ========================================================================== */

.ir {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    *text-indent: -9999px;
}

.ir:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 150%;
}

.hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.visuallyhidden {
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

.visuallyhidden.focusable:active,
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus {
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

.invisible {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}

/* ==========================================================================
   Print styles
   ========================================================================== */

@media print {
    * {
        background: transparent !important;
        color: #000 !important; /* Black prints faster: h5bp.com/s */
        box-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    a,
    a:visited {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    a[href]:after {
        content: " (" attr(href) ")";
    }

    abbr[title]:after {
        content: " (" attr(title) ")";
    }

    /*
     * Don't show links for images, or javascript/internal links
     */

    .ir a:after,
    a[href^="javascript:"]:after,
    a[href^="#"]:after {
        content: "";
    }

    pre,
    blockquote {
        border: 1px solid #999;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    thead {
        display: table-header-group; /* h5bp.com/t */
    }

    tr,
    img {
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    img {
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

    @page {
        margin: 0.5cm;
    }

    p,
    h2,
    h3 {
        orphans: 3;
        widows: 3;
    }

    h2,
    h3 {
        page-break-after: avoid;
    }
}

.fb_iframe_widget{
    padding: 5px 0 10px 0;
    height: 12px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*preloader*/
body:after{
    display:none;
    content:url('../img/mathieu.jpg') url('../img/hirmane.jpg') url('../img/daniel.jpg');
}
.ieshow{
    display: none;
}
.ng-modal-overlay {
  /* A dark translucent div that covers the whole screen */
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:#000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.ng-modal-dialog {
  /* A centered div above the overlay with a box shadow. */
  z-index:10000;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; /* Default */

  /* Center the dialog */
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;

}
.ng-modal-dialog-content {
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 80px #000;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.ng-modal-dialog-content p{
    text-transform: inherit;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    line-height: 1.3;
}
.ng-modal-dialog-content em{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    font-family: PerpetuaMT-Bold;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.ng-modal-dialog-content h2{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.ng-modal-dialog-content img{
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 100%;
}
.ng-modal-close {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: 'arial', 'sans-serif';
  float: right;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had two brackets after a css-selector, thus closing the media-selector.

```
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand whats your issue is exactly, but try referring below (one of my previous answers posted below)

include this in `<head></head>` (if you have not)

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> <-- user-scalable=yes if you want user to allow zoom -->
```

change you @media style as this // change width as per your requirements

```
@media only screen (max-width: 500px) {
 // or as per your needs, as I try to explain below
}
```

Now I try to explain maybe..:)

```
@media (max-width:500px)
```

for a window with a `max-width` of `500px` that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px)
```

for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of `500px` apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px)
```

Here is a [quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘`only`’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "`only`", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

I try to put some more information here, gathered from web.

```
@media all and (min-width: 500px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 500px) and (min-width: 300px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 299px) {
}
```

```
If
```

That's what media queries are: logical if statements. "If" these things are true about the browser, use the CSS inside.

```
And
```

The keyword and.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}

Or
```

Comma separate.

```
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Technically these are treated like to separate media queries, but that is effectively and or.

```
Not
```

Reverse the logic with the keyword not.

```
@media not all and (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Just doing not (max-width: 600px) doesn't seem to work for me, hence the slightly funky syntax above. Perhaps someone can explain that to me. Note that not only works for the current media query, so if you comma separate, it only affects the media query it is within. Also note that not reverses the logic for the entire media query as a whole, not individual parts of it. not x and y = not (x and y) ≠ (not x) and y

**Exclusive**

To ensure that only one media query is in effect at time, make the numbers (or whatever) such that that is possible. It may be easier to mentally manage them this way.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Logically this is a bit like a switch statement, only without a simple way to do "if none of these match do this" like default.

**Overriding**

There is nothing preventing more than one media query from being true at the same time. It may be more efficient to use this in some cases rather than making them all exclusive.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Media queries add no specificity to the selectors they contain, but source order still matters. The above will work because they are ordered correctly. Swap that order and at browser window widths above 800px the background would be red, perhaps inquisitively.

**Mobile First**

Your small screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets larger you override what you need to. So, min-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

**Desktop First**

Your large screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets smaller you override what you need to. So, max-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

You can be as complex as you want with this.

```
@media 
  only screen and (min-width: 100px),
  not all and (min-width: 100px),
  not print and (min-height: 100px),
  (color),
  (min-height: 100px) and (max-height: 1000px),
  handheld and (orientation: landscape)
{
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Note the only keyword was intended to prevent non-media-query supporting browsers to not load the stylesheet or use the styles. Not sure how useful that ever was / still is.

[And for media queries priorites](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/media_queries_priority.htm)

sources : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored-or-overridden/10816111#10816111) [two](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) [three](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) [four](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) [five](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)