# website responsive showing good in firefox but not in mobile?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I can't figure out the issue. I searched a lot and after that. I am here for help so guys please help me. Below is the HTML I use:

```
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,          user-scalable=0">
```

and these are the media queries

```
     @media all and (max-width: 1400px) { }
     @media all and (max-width: 1024px) { }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) { }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { }
     @media only screen and (max-width: 320px) { }
```

Help me identify what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media all and (min-width: 1400px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 1399px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 768px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 480px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 479px) and (min-width: 320px) {
}

@media all and (max-width: 319px) {
}
```

This in `<head></head>`

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> <-- user-scalable=yes if you want user to allow zoom -->
```

change you @media style as this // change width as per your requirements

```
@media only screen (max-width: 500px) {
 // or as per your needs, as I try to explain below
}
```

Now I try to explain maybe..:)

```
@media (max-width:500px)
```

for a window with a `max-width` of `500px` that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px)
```

for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of `500px` apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px)
```

Here is a [quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘`only`’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "`only`", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

I try to put some more information here, gathered from web.

```
If
```

That's what media queries are: logical if statements. "If" these things are true about the browser, use the CSS inside.

```
And
```

The keyword and.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}

Or
```

Comma separate.

```
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Technically these are treated like to separate media queries, but that is effectively and or.

```
Not
```

Reverse the logic with the keyword not.

```
@media not all and (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Just doing not (max-width: 600px) doesn't seem to work for me, hence the slightly funky syntax above. Perhaps someone can explain that to me. Note that not only works for the current media query, so if you comma separate, it only affects the media query it is within. Also note that not reverses the logic for the entire media query as a whole, not individual parts of it. not x and y = not (x and y) ≠ (not x) and y

**Exclusive**

To ensure that only one media query is in effect at time, make the numbers (or whatever) such that that is possible. It may be easier to mentally manage them this way.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Logically this is a bit like a switch statement, only without a simple way to do "if none of these match do this" like default.

**Overriding**

There is nothing preventing more than one media query from being true at the same time. It may be more efficient to use this in some cases rather than making them all exclusive.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Media queries add no specificity to the selectors they contain, but source order still matters. The above will work because they are ordered correctly. Swap that order and at browser window widths above 800px the background would be red, perhaps inquisitively.

**Mobile First**

Your small screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets larger you override what you need to. So, min-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

**Desktop First**

Your large screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets smaller you override what you need to. So, max-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

You can be as complex as you want with this.

```
@media 
  only screen and (min-width: 100px),
  not all and (min-width: 100px),
  not print and (min-height: 100px),
  (color),
  (min-height: 100px) and (max-height: 1000px),
  handheld and (orientation: landscape)
{
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Note the only keyword was intended to prevent non-media-query supporting browsers to not load the stylesheet or use the styles. Not sure how useful that ever was / still is.

[And for media queries priorites](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/media_queries_priority.htm)

sources : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored-or-overridden/10816111#10816111) [two](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) [three](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) [four](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) [five](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Comment: so can u paste your css or media queries here?

Comment: actually its a whole website too many lines .......firefox is showing properly but chrome doesn't show good a mobile screen(320,480px\) and mobile also showing like if all stuff is broken

Comment: I am sure if you use above codes, the starting one which I made for u will work, I can,t identify the problem without having a look to ur codes.

Comment: your queries are working fine till 1024px but after that they are not even applied

Comment: check for codes that u r putting in 1023px - 768px? are they different from 1024px - 1399px ?

Comment: can u share your css on some link or something?

Comment: only the responsive one? i can't share the html?

Comment: only queries or the queries with css code for content?

Comment: queries with ss content!

Comment: did you found the mistakes

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/9ZY5G/1/ you haven't applied codes as I posted, even there was issues with applying media queries, u had put other media queries in 1024px - 1399px media queries. Anyways I hope ur problem is now solved.

Comment: still the same no changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined css properties for different medias, how do you expect the browser to render it?

You need to for example:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
   #header
     {
     width:100%
     background:red;
      }


    }
```

Comment: i have defined css for different screen sizes and firefox is showing everything properly but in mobile everything looks broken

Comment: Maybe you should place your css here so that we can see what is causing this issue?

Comment: I have placed the css above please see