# responsive webdesign: Media Queries not working for other screens

Tags: css, media-queries

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {}
```

I am using these mediaqueries and these are working fine but when I see my website at 1280px resolution, it does not work

Comment: Which one media query i have to use for 1280 to 1024 resolution?

Comment: Please could you explain what doesn't work? Could you post a fiddle with the specific issue?

Comment: Dear FabrizioCalderan my these media query are working fine but when i am checking in 1280 resolution, i want add new query for this resolution but it is getting this media query
@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {}

i want to add new media query which should work specifically for 1280 to 1024 resolution

Comment: @HMSDesignz - The last time I checked, working fine and not working are the opposite. Do you mean they work when the resolution is an exact match but not when the screen has a higher res?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) and and (max-width:1280px)
{
 .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@HMS Designz, If you want to access media query 1280 to 1024 resolution. You can try like this.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024px) and (max-width:1280px) {}
```

Comment: And if you are using your media query at 1280px resolution then it will pick this media query

@media only screen and (min-width : 1224px) {}

As here you are taking minimum 1224px and other one is greater than 1280px.
HTH

Comment: @media i added this query but browser getting prefer first this query (min-width : 1224px)  so should i remove this query?

Comment: Where is your confusion.. browser will prefer the query you have defined. So if you want to use @media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {} style to 1280px then just change (min-width : 1824px) to (max-width : 1824px) and (min-width : 1224px) {} to (max-width : 1224px) {}

Answer (score 0):

You are not create any media query for 1280 px resolutions. First create media query for that resolution using following media query.

```
@media screen and (min-width:1024) and (max-width:1280px)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media all and (min-width: 1280px) {
 /* css for width greater than 1280px */
}

@media all and (max-width: 1280px) and (min-width: 1024px) {
 /* css for width between 1280px and 1024px */
}

@media all and (max-width: 1023px) {
 /* css for width less than 1024px */
}
```

[**Here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995) is detailed explainition of media queries.

include this in `<head></head>` (if you have not)

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" /> <-- user-scalable=yes if you want user to allow zoom -->
```

change you @media style as this // change width as per your requirements

```
@media only screen (max-width: 500px) {
 // or as per your needs, as I try to explain below
}
```

Now I try to explain maybe..:)

```
@media (max-width:500px)
```

for a window with a `max-width` of `500px` that you want to apply these styles. At that size you would be talking about anything smaller than a desktop screen in most cases.

```
@media screen and (max-width:500px)
```

for a device with a `screen` and a window with `max-width` of `500px` apply the style. This is almost identical to the above except you are specifying `screen` as opposed to the [other media types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23423868/css-getting-changed-when-applying-css-media-queries-for-responsive-design/23423995#23423995)  the most common other one being `print`.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:500px)
```

Here is a [quote](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#media0) straight from W3C to explain this one.

> The keyword ‘`only`’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User   agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.

As there is no such media type as "`only`", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers.

```
If
```

That's what media queries are: logical if statements. "If" these things are true about the browser, use the CSS inside.

```
And
```

The keyword and.

```
@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}

Or
```

Comma separate.

```
@media (max-width: 600px), (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Technically these are treated like to separate media queries, but that is effectively and or.

```
Not
```

Reverse the logic with the keyword not.

```
@media not all and (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Just doing not (max-width: 600px) doesn't seem to work for me, hence the slightly funky syntax above. Perhaps someone can explain that to me. Note that not only works for the current media query, so if you comma separate, it only affects the media query it is within. Also note that not reverses the logic for the entire media query as a whole, not individual parts of it. not x and y = not (x and y) ≠ (not x) and y

**Exclusive**

To ensure that only one media query is in effect at time, make the numbers (or whatever) such that that is possible. It may be easier to mentally manage them this way.

```
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 401px) and (max-width: 800px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 801px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Logically this is a bit like a switch statement, only without a simple way to do "if none of these match do this" like default.

**Overriding**

There is nothing preventing more than one media query from being true at the same time. It may be more efficient to use this in some cases rather than making them all exclusive.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  html { background: red; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  html { background: blue; }
}
```

Media queries add no specificity to the selectors they contain, but source order still matters. The above will work because they are ordered correctly. Swap that order and at browser window widths above 800px the background would be red, perhaps inquisitively.

**Mobile First**

Your small screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets larger you override what you need to. So, min-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

**Desktop First**

Your large screen styles are in your regular screen CSS and then as the screen gets smaller you override what you need to. So, max-width media queries in general.

```
html { background: red; }

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  html { background: green; }
}
```

You can be as complex as you want with this.

```
@media 
  only screen and (min-width: 100px),
  not all and (min-width: 100px),
  not print and (min-height: 100px),
  (color),
  (min-height: 100px) and (max-height: 1000px),
  handheld and (orientation: landscape)
{
  html { background: red; }
}
```

Note the only keyword was intended to prevent non-media-query supporting browsers to not load the stylesheet or use the styles. Not sure how useful that ever was / still is.

[And for media queries priorites](https://developer.tizen.org/dev-guide/2.2.1/org.tizen.web.appprogramming/html/guide/w3c_guide/dom_guide/media_queries_priority.htm)

sources : [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815651/why-is-my-css-media-query-being-ignored-or-overridden/10816111#10816111) [two](http://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) [three](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) [four](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) [five](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)