# Responsive media query not working in Google Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, width, media-queries

I have written a piece of CSS code to fluidly switch my site layout's width based on the user's screen width. If the user has less screen estate available, the layout's width increases to fill more of the window and leave less whitespace, and if they have more space, the layout shrinks to maintain an appealing look.

I use the following code to achieve this:

```
#bg{
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #0f0f0f 0%,#222222 400px);
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #0f0f0f 0%,#222222 400px);
    background:-o-linear-gradient(90deg, #0f0f0f 0%,#222222 400px);
    background:linear-gradient(90deg, #0f0f0f 0%,#222222 400px);
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:1.6rem;
    border-width:0 0.1rem 0.1rem 0.1rem;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:#303030 #101010 #000;
    border-radius:0.8rem;
    min-width:94.2rem
}

@media (min-width: 70rem){
    #bg{
        border-radius:4px;
        border-radius:0.4rem;
        width:90%
    }

}

@media (min-width: 91rem){
    #bg{
        width:80%
    }

}

@media (min-width: 112rem){
    #bg{
        width:70%
    }

}
```

This works just fine in Firefox 30, however Google Chrome **always** displays the element at 70% width.

Previously, I had also used *max-width* in the queries, in which case Chrome would do the inverse thing; it would always display the element at 90%, no matter how much I resize the browser window.

The rules are compiled using SASS. What exactly is the problem here? How can I alter the query to work in all browsers?

The affected website can be found [at this link](http://www.unrealsp.org/).

Comment: Could you please show an excerpt of the DOM structure? Have you looked at the compiled CSS if it's valid?

Comment: @try-catch-finally I'm not sure how to make a standalone example of the site structure, as it's a bit more complex, but I've added a link to the website in question. Also, the code you see is the compiled CSS.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

add this line in `<head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: This doesn't have any effect on desktop browsers.

Comment: can you send me please link of your website

Comment: The question was posted 3 years ago. I'm pretty sure that by now they have either fixed the issue or abandoned the project. And there *is* a link to the website in the question.

Comment: Yes, "viewport" meta tag! Just spent an hour troubleshooting perfect media queries when for some reason my template was missing the "viewport" tag.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know why my media queries were not working on chrome. It was lacking viewport meta tag.

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the problem? This answer would be much more useful if we could know why this works.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Chrome (or any browser) on a **desktop**, the **browser zoom should be 100%. No more or no less. Otherwise, responsive doesn't work** (use Ctrl + scroll in *Windows*, or Cmd +/- in *Mac* to adjust).

Comment: This is not true, the zoom option is only for the browser window and not for the website content.

Comment: @Dexter I never say that zoom option is for website content.

Comment: Helped in my case. When zoom is not 100%, then this percentage is applied to media queries. For example @media (min-width: 768px) with zoom level 90% is applied only at 691 pixels (768*0.90).

Comment: Yes，save me a lot of time!!

Comment: The viewport declaration must come before you define the CSS media query. I had mine below it in the header and it didn't help.

Answer (score 6):

You can tweak this to your needs

```
// css for mobile here
// ...

/* desktop */
@media (min-width: 900px) and (orientation: landscape)
{
    // css for desktop here
    // ...
}
```

And don't forget

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: to me it was <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

Answer (score 3):

I had an issue with chrome that it was loading css once we cross the pixel which suppose to be effected, added decimal value's fixed my issue like.

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px){...}
```

Same followed in bootstrap 4 css as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body{
            background:green;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            body{
                background:yellow;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this more usual syntax works better:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 112rem){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for the more proper syntax, however this does not solve the issue on Chrome.

Comment: Just noticed you've added a link. Those media queries are working fine in Chrome (Mac) for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it's similar to Hassan's response, just add `minimum-scale=1`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All are correct, but Chech [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/default-sizes-for-twitter-bootstraps-media-queries)

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {...}
```

NOT

> @media screen and (min-width: 320px){ ... }

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

        /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
        @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) {

        }

        /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
        @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {

        }

        /* Small Devices, Tablets */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {

        }

        /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 992px) {

        }

        /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
        @media only screen and (min-width : 1200px) {

        }



        /*==========  Non-Mobile First Method  ==========*/

        /* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
        @media only screen and (max-width : 1200px) {

        }

        /* Medium Devices, Desktops */
        @media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {

        }

        /* Small Devices, Tablets */
        @media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {

        }

        /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */ 
        @media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {

        }

        /* Custom, iPhone Retina */ 
        @media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

please close your code with ';' and try this

```
@media (min-width: 70rem){
#bg{
    border-radius:4px !important;
    border-radius:0.4rem !important;
    width:90% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others argue above, on a desktop you need to check that the zoom is set to 100% as well as use the viewport meta tag

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I was trying to use a media query of a style `@media (width > x)` as opposed to `@media (min-width: x)`. Firefox handled the media query properly, but Chrome ignored it.

Answer (score 0):

Also to point out.

if you write a media query like this
`

```
@media screen and(max-width:500px){
    body {
        color:green;   
    }
}
```

`

If it does not work, the problem is with not spacing the word and and the bracket like so `and (`